# OpenAM OpenDJ dockerisation issue: Fails to redeploy using old data source

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, openam, opendj

Facing a critical issue while the dockerization process of the  OpenAM-OpenDJ)

If the OpenAM container crashes or fails and we forced to redeploy OpenAM again, it will not connect to older OpenDJ, we need to reset OpenDJ again to make it functional

If any possible way to overcome this issue

Created configuration folder and tomcat web-apps folder as volumes in docker, but while if we forced to recreate a new container using the older volume, it again goes to fresh installation.


Is there any possible way to overcome this issue ??

Comment: Can you give more information on your setup? How do you setup AM? What is it using DS for (User source, CTS, Config Store)? How is your Dockerfile looking like? How do you run the containers? Without an answer to these questions it's hard to get an idea of the fault.

Comment: once we deploy openam it will create some core files in /root directory. Just need to mount that directory it will fix our issues. The directory contains OpenDJ configuration details and other. while openam container destroys, then next restart will use the mounted point to start.

Comment: @jonasheinisch Updated the fix below

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue. 
We getting this issue due to failed to mount the configuration folder directory as a volume.

ie, while deploying the openam.war inside the webapps folder, it will create the configuration details in /root/openam location.

Please mount the volume , then the server will restart using the existing data.

Please see the openam configuration

```
  "networks":
  "network":
    "external":
      "name": "appliance"
"services":
  "container_openam":
    "build":
      "context": "identity-openam"
      "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    "container_name": "identity-openam" 
    "image": "identity-openam:latest"
    "networks":
    - "network"
    "ports":
    - "8080:8080"
    "restart": "always"
    "volumes":
    - "openam_configuration:/root/sso"
    - "openam_core:/root/.openamcfg"
  "container_opendj":
    "build":
      "args":
      - "PORT=1389"
      - "LDAPS_PORT=1636"
      - "BASE_DN=dc=ds,dc=test,dc=com"
      - "ROOT_USER_DN=cn=Directory Manager"
      - "ROOT_PASSWORD=rdddE"
      "context": "identity-persistence-opendj-ldap"
      "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    "container_name": "identity-persistence-opendj-ldap"
    "image": "identity-persistence-opendj-ldap:latest"
    "networks":
    - "network"
    "ports":
    - "1389:1389"
    - "4444:4444"
    "restart": "always"
    "volumes":
    - "storage:/opt/opendj/db"  
"version": "3.4"
"volumes":
  "openam_configuration":
    "name": "openam_configuration"
  "openam_core":
    "name": "openam_core"
  "storage":
    "name": "identity-icampp-opendj-openam"
```

Comment: Can you share your solution (as code / command line) to help others solve their related issues?